# MapView with ItemizedOverlay and map scrolling

Tags: android, dictionary, android-mapview

I have a problem with custom ItemizedOverlay on the MapView in Android.

**What I've done:** Very simple offspring of ItemizedOverlay class that only wraps my own type of items and uses ItemizedOverlay for all the hard work.

**What works:** Nearly everything - items are drawn properly, I can tap them etc.

**The problem:** If I drag the map in the view by the map itself, I can scroll it without a problems. But if I try to start moving the map over one of items from my overlay (eg. "dragging map by item"), it doesn't move.

This is really problem, because if I have "a bit more" items, there is no way to drag the map (without un-zooming and grabbing map outside items).

This problem occurs even if I don't handle any events generated by ItemizedOverlay (eg. with onTap() commented out in my overlay).

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: .. only idea of solving it I found so far was to override onTouchEvent(), but this doesn't seem to me like the best solution ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, we solved this issue.

But only solution we found was writing our own version of "ItemizedOverlay" (without inheriting it). Eg. we're drawing our own overlay and we handle "tap events".